# Angular EventEmitter not emitting event

Tags: angular

I have Angular vertical stepper(angular material) where each step is a separate component and there is a parent component where I am calling all these components. I am trying to pass data between the parent and child components. There is an @Output EventEmitter event in the child component that is getting called but the function in the parent component is not getting called.

Note: The EventEmitter event is actually inside a subscribe method.

*Child Component ts file:*

```
@Output() sampleEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

sampleFunction (){
    this.someService.someMethod.subscribe((data) => {
           this.sampleEvent.emit(data);
           // some other functions are there like console.log and 
           //  snackbar message which are getting called
    })
    
}
```

*Parent Component html file:*

```
<child-component (sampleEvent)=parentFunction($event)></child-component>
```

*Parent Component ts file:*

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent; 

parentFunction(data) {
   
   console.log(data); //not getting called
}

funtionABC() {
   this.anotherFunction();
}

anotherFunction() {
  this.child.sampleFunction();
}
```

Comment: Sure you imported `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core` and not `from 'events` or `from 'stream'`? Because `EventEmitter<T>` expects one type argument

Comment: @Pieterjan is the most likely answer. That happens to a lot of people.

Comment: @Pieterjan, yes syntax wise and import wise everything is fine

Comment: Are you calling the function `sampleFunction()` in your child component? Also, try console.log inside the subscribe callback, is it getting called?

Comment: @Maher, sampleFunction() is present in child component, but i m calling it in the parent component and then i m trying to send data (that we get inside sampleFunction) back to the parent component

Answer (score 0):

You are not triggering the event. You have set up this function, but there is no call to it.

```
anotherFunction() {
  this.child.sampleFunction();
}
```

You can setup a button on Parent, and on click call it. And probably Angular vertical stepper has some other trigger that will execute the event so no button will be needed.

```
<button (click)=anotherFunction()>Trigger</button>
```

Here you have an stackblitz demo, if it is not working for you, can you please provide a demo for better understanding of the issue. [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vruwr8?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: yes, i apologize for not mentioning, i have edited my post (i m actually calling the another function)

Comment: @SnehankaRoy i have added a stackblitz demo to the answer. can you pls check